# find text and create parent tag jquery

Tags: jquery, html, find, createelement

Find text after img tag and create p tag for the text is this possible  with jquery please help me

See here ;

```
<p>
  <img src="img.jpg" />
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>
```

This is my HTML code i need to create like this

```
<p>
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</p>
```

Is this possible with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the next sibling of the `img` elements and see whether it is an non-empty text node, if so then wrap it with a `p` node using [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

```
$('p img').each(function () {
    var next = this.nextSibling;
    if (next && next.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && $.trim(next.nodeValue) != '') {
        $(next).wrap('<p/>')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wN498/)

Comment: here next.nodeType == 3 how i know that == 3 means what ?

Comment: @Riturajratan `next.nodeType == 3` is checking for textnode .

Comment: it is the value for text node... I already updated the answer to use a constant

Comment: Can we make it as for evry text node

Comment: see in my question there is text after img right? so without finding img can we create parent tag for text

Comment: @Sam can you give a sample of the markup you are trying to target... if the html is `<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</p>` then what to do

Comment: actually am using dynamic content from xml to show in a html page there text should be in a paragraph so i want add p tag for text in everywhere